# Flutter create a custom design button

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to create this type of button in flutter

[image]

Need to know what type of button is this? I have check previously these are some specific type of button need to know is there any widget for this type of buttons ?

Comment: you can check this one https://morioh.com/p/e16733007adc

Answer (score 0):

**100% custom buttons**

[image]

**Source Code Use  `flutter_neumorphic: ^3.0.3` package**

```
 Container(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    color: const Color(0xf0222324),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [

                      GestureDetector(onTap:(){},
                        child: Neumorphic(
                            style: NeumorphicStyle(
                                shape: NeumorphicShape.convex,
                                shadowLightColor: Colors.white38,
                                shadowDarkColor:Colors.black,
shadowLightColorEmboss: Colors.white,
shadowDarkColorEmboss: Colors.black,
                                boxShape: NeumorphicBoxShape.roundRect(BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                                depth: 8,
                                lightSource: LightSource.topLeft,
                                color: Color(0xf8a70707)
                            ),
                            child: Container(width: 300,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 7,horizontal: 15),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,child:
                              Text('RELOAD LIVEWALLET',style:TextStyle(fontSize: 20,color: Colors.white)),)

                        ),
                      ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20,),
                        Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [

                          GestureDetector(onTap:(){},
                          child: Neumorphic(
                              style: NeumorphicStyle(
                                  shape: NeumorphicShape.convex,
                                  shadowLightColor: Colors.white38,
                                  shadowDarkColor:Colors.black,
                                  shadowLightColorEmboss: Colors.white,
                                  shadowDarkColorEmboss: Colors.black,
                                  boxShape: NeumorphicBoxShape.roundRect(BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                                  depth: 8,
                                  lightSource: LightSource.topLeft,
                                  color: Color(0xf8282626)
                              ),
                              child: Container(width: 150,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 7,horizontal: 15),
                                alignment: Alignment.center,child:
                                Row(
                                  children: [Icon(Icons.local_atm,color: Colors.white,),
                                    Text(' WITHDRAW',style:TextStyle(fontSize: 17,color: Colors.white)),
                                  ],
                                ),)

                          ),
                        ), SizedBox(width: 20),
                          GestureDetector(onTap:(){},
                          child: Neumorphic(
                              style: NeumorphicStyle(
                                  shape: NeumorphicShape.convex,
                                  shadowLightColor: Colors.white38,
                                  shadowDarkColor:Colors.black,
                                  shadowLightColorEmboss: Colors.white,
                                  shadowDarkColorEmboss: Colors.black,
                                  boxShape: NeumorphicBoxShape.roundRect(BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                                  depth: 8,
                                  lightSource: LightSource.topLeft,
                                  color: Color(0xf8282626)
                              ),
                              child: Container(width: 150,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 7,horizontal: 15),
                                alignment: Alignment.center,child:
                                Row(
                                  children: [Icon(Icons.workspaces_filled,color: Colors.white,),
                                    Text(' TRANSFER',style:TextStyle(fontSize: 17,color: Colors.white)),
                                  ],
                                ),)

                          ),
                        )],)
                    ],),
                  ),
```